# Same File Styles in ReactJS (similar to VueJS)

Tags: reactjs, jsx, styled-components

In VueJS you have a `style` section where you can add in custom css.  With React, you have `StyledComponents` where you can create a component with css functionality (and do so in the same file).  Alternatively, in react you can import an external style sheet and use those styles.

What I am wondering is whether or not there is a way to create the Vue like functionality in a ReactJS file -- that is, something akin to a `css file` within a `react/jsx` file?

For example, this is what I do **not** want:

```
Const Input = styled.input``
const Button = styled.button``
Const PostList = styled.div``
// etc
```

Rather, I want something like this:

```
const Styles = `

 input { // add input styles here }
 .button { // add button styles }
 .post-list { // add post-list styles here }
 // etc

`
```

I'm not saying it has to be the exact syntax above, but rather that in one variable (or function or object) I can create all of my css styles related to that file using normla css syntax?  The difference between this and Styled Components is that with Styled Components a) I am not creating class names and b) I have to create a new component each and every time.

I actually want to create class-names, not components -- and I want to do it in one go (like a normal css file, just within a react.js(x) file).

In short, is something like this possible in React -- and, if so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: This is absolutely doable, this pattern is called CSS-in-JS. Take a look at [Material-UI's implementation of styling](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) and here's [a good article](https://medium.com/@dmitrynozhenko/9-ways-to-implement-css-in-react-js-ccea4d543aa3) showing most different ways of styling in React. These might not be the exact implementation you need but will hopefully give you an idea of how to implement it for your use case

Comment: you may consider looking into CSS modules, which looks like what suits you better

Answer (score -1):

You can use **styled-components** to achieve that. also, you can use props with it
[Here is the link](https://styled-components.com/)

Answer (score -2):

You can create a css file and import it wherever you need. for eg. if you want to create some common css classes and use it through out your application. then create a normal css file and write your css rules.

and then import that css file in your main/root component.

for eg. if your css file name is `helper.css`

and your root component is `App.js`

then import it like this

```
import React from "react";
import "./helper.css";

function App(){
  return "root component"
}
```

There is no special way to write/create css file in react. You do it how you do it in simple html/css project